# How to search for existence of record in one table from another using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I use php and mysql. I have two tables,

`table A (Id: auto-increment , idno)`
 `table B (Id:auto-increment, sidno)`.

Table A contains about 3000 records and Table B contains about 27000 records. I want to search whether each of the records in table A exist in table B, if not print the records that does not exist in table B.

I tried to retrieve the records in table A and checking them against table A, but I could not succeed. And it took a very long time to finished the query.

And I have searched throughout but could not get something like this.

Please can anybody help me.

Thanks!

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: Are you looking for a Select query to solve your problem? What is that you have tried already? Can you elaborate more on your requirement?

Comment: TableA: field1 (int, primary key,  auto increment),  field2 (int) and TableB: field1 (int, primary key,  auto increment),  field2 (int)

Comment: @neels I tried to select the record from both table and compare the two. I also tried several mysql functions such as HAVING COUNT, LIKE COUNT but I can't make it.

Comment: Did you try the solution posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query might return all the idno which are not in table B

```
 SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `idno` NOT IN (SELECT `sidno` FROM tableB)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21b1f/1/0)

Comment: Am trying to run thee query as follow:  $qr = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `idno` NOT IN (SELECT `sidno` FROM tableB)";  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr)) { echo $row[sidno]; } but I am getting error due to mysql_fetch_array I replaced it with mysql_fetch_assocs but having the same problem. Please help me

Comment: Warning mysql_fetch_assoc() not a valid mysql argument on line 38

Comment: i think you have problem in your query. Please print `mysql_error()` and check whether query runs successfully

Comment: you have missed one closing `)` bracket in your query. Please add that and try running the query again.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly the problem, I missed one closing bracket ")". I really appreciate for all your help and for everyone's concern too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM table2 t where sid NOT IN (select id from table1) ;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73c957/1)

Comment: This is what I got when the query is run:

Comment: do you want query like this or any different query ?

Answer (score 0):

like this

select * from tableA where Minus select id from where tableA.id=tableB.id;

[MINUS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php)
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this:

```
SELECT tableB.Id, tableB.sidno
FROM tableA
RIGHT JOIN tableB ON tableA.Id = tableB.ID
WHERE tableA.Id = 'NULL';
```

This should give you all the records you want.